# Check if drupal token is empty or not

Tags: xml, drupal, token

My goal is to parse an xml code using drupal, to an external website, where it will be processed and saved in a database.

For this purpose i`m using the rules module. But i got a tiny problem that i don't seem to be able to solve.

For example i take one of the xml lines:

```
<FullName>[account:field-bedrijfsnaam-bedrijf]</FullName>
```

If the drupal token is empty the field should turn to:

```
<FullName xsi:nil="true" />
```

I tried some php code to check if the token is empty by doing this:

```
<?php if(!empty('[account:field-bedrijfsnaam-bedrijf]')): ?>
    <FullName>[account:field-bedrijfsnaam-bedrijf]</FullName>
<?php else: ?>
    <FullName xsi:nil="true" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

The empty function failed, so i tried if(strlen([account:field-bedrijfsnaam-bedrijf]) > 0) instead, but no success. The token doesn't seem to be empty using strlen and the empty function doesn't work at all.

[image: Image with php evaluation displayed]

Beneath the field where i've entered my xml code, drupal says i can use the $account and $site variables for evaluation. I where wondering if i could use these to check if the field data is empty or not?

Its an object, so how do i correctly check if a field in $account is empty or not? Since i can't use print_r(data is sended to external site), i don't see how to do this.

If it's not possible, does anyone know how to work around it...?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) drupal function to get the variable and make sure it exists

```
if(field_get_items('user', $account, 'field-bedrijfsnaam-bedrijf')) {
   // code here when it is not empty
} else {
  // Code when it's empty
}
```

The first param passed to the function is the entity_type. So if someone else views this that will need to be replaced with whatever entity type they are using.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, care to explain? How would an if statement checking if a value exists create errors? I've done this on many sites before

Comment: There's a very basic error in both code samples. Try 'em and you'll see (even outside the context of Drupal, you'll still get a fatal error). Actually, it might not be fatal. You might just get notices about undefined constants. Either way, it won't work verbatim. FWIW the logic in your answer is spot on, just the implementation that needs a bit of a tweak (using [`field_get_items()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) would also be preferable) :)

Comment: Oh wait, there's another error. the `->` operator is very much not used to access arrays, it's for accessing object members

Comment: That was actually a typo, whoops. The variables available to you in Rules are objects, so that's correct. I really don't think field_get_items is the right solution. With that you are making a db query to the backend of drupal, which is ridiculous because you already have a copy of the object/node available to you in the context of rules

Comment: @Constarr Should be `$account->{"field-bedrijfsnaam-bedrijf"}`

Comment: @som Nope, should be `$account->field_bedrijfsnaam_bedrijf`

Comment: @Constarr Using the API isn't 'ridiculous', it's just good practice. What you're forgetting is that Drupal sites are multi-lingual. `field_get_items()` handles language negotiation for you, whereas your code doesn't. If the node has been loaded, and the field has been loaded (which both have at this point), `field_get_items()` doesn't incur a database hit as the data is statically cached anyway. There's no scenario where directly accessing the entity fields is preferable to using `field_get_items()`

Comment: None seem to work yet. Concerning the field_get_items(), what is the best way to implement it. Maybe i can give it a try.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus Something like: `$field_items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_bedrijfsnaam_bedrijf');`

Comment: Thanx clive, you're solution works! Thank you all very much for the help.

Comment: Ah, I had a misunderstanding of how that function worked. I just read the source and you are correct. The Drupal sites I work on are usually just have language undefined so I forgot about that. I bow down to your superior knowledge. :P

Comment: Can someone post the right answer, so i can make the post accepted as answer?

Comment: Answered! :) Thanx again folks :)